# Instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400014 [MIPS]

Tags: mips, qtspim

Every file i try to load into QTSPIM gives me this error:

Instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400014
  [0x00400014] 0x0c000000  jal 0x00000000 [main]    ; 188: jal main

I am loading the file and the file does have a "main:" in it and if I put ".global main" before "main" it does the same thing. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The directive you're looking for is `.globl`, not `.global`.

So:

```
.globl main
.text
main:
    # Awesome code goes here
```

Comment: Works just fine for me in QtSpim 9.1.12. Make sure you have at least one instruction following `main:`.

Comment: Im using 9.1.17 on a mac, Im sure it is all very much alike. Very strange